# How to turn off a sensor of Pepper?

Tags: sensors, pepper

I am currently using the humanoid robot "Pepper" and I want to deactivate Pepper's Laser sensors located on its legs. I looked at "SOFTBANK ROBOTICS DOCUMENTATION" and it only says "Sets the operation mode." But I have no idea how to go into operation mode. If you have any ideas, could you teach me how to deactivate its laser sensors?

Comment: I do not know if this is what you need - you may use [ALMotion::setExternalCollisionProtectionEnabled](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/motion/reflexes-external-collision-api.html#ALMotionProxy::setExternalCollisionProtectionEnabled__ssCR.bCR) to turn Pepper's collision detection on and off.

Answer (score 1):

There is an option to turn off the lasers using void ALLaserProxy::laserOFF() , I found this on this [site](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-1/naoqi/sensors/allaser-api.html#allaser-api)

Comment: This piece of API is for NAOs with special heads equipped with lasers. It is not meant to control Pepper's base lasers. If this works this is interesting, but as you can see it is not officially documented.

Answer (score -1):

There is no official way to turn them off.